# best way to call two database servers

Tags: java, mysql, select

i want to call two table of different database at once.table of database A contains user id and table of database B contains user location with the user id, so i want to join these two tables and get the location corresponding to user_id.database A and B are in two different servers. so how can i join these two tables. if it is not possible to join this, is there any efficient way to do this.please help.i'm trying to do this using java, mysql.

```
 ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id FROM A.users");
 rs = ps.executeQuery();
 while(rs.next())
    {
    //call select statement for database B to get the location for each user id             

    }
```

please suggest an efficient way to do this

```
Id  User_id
===========
1   44
2   23

User_id     location
====================
44          india
23          us
```

Comment: I want to clarify: different database server / different database schema ?

Comment: Are the databases on the same mysql-server-instance?

Comment: @PeterRader *A and B are in two different servers* maybe this sentece clarifies your question.

Comment: You need to have two connections, one pointing to the server where table A belongs and another for table B. And yes, this means to have two `Connection` objects: `Connection conTableA; Connection conTableB;`.

Comment: yes im trying to maintain two connections, but if i do as the above code then if there are 1000 user ids, then i have to execute the select statement in 1000 times,is there any way to execute this as a batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing `user_id` is a `long`.

```
PreparedStatement psUserLocation = conB.prepareStatement("SELECT location FROM B.users WHERE user_id = ?");
while(rs.next()) {
    //call select statement for database B to get the location for each user id
    long userId = rs.getLong(user_id);
    psUserLocation.setLong(1, userId)
    ResultSet userLocation = ps.executeQuery();
    // Do whatever with the location(s)
}
```

**EDIT**: one query for all users instead of one query per user:

```
private final static String QUERY = "SELECT user_id, location FROM B.users WHERE user_id IN (%a)";

StringBuilder userList = new StringBuilder();
while(rs.next()) {
    long userId = rs.getLong(user_id);
    userList.append(userId);
    if (!rs.isLast()) {
        userList.append(",");
    }
}

String usersLocationQuery = QUERY.replaceAll("%a", userList.toString());
PreparedStatement psUsersLocation = conB.prepareStatement(usersLocationQuery);
ResultSet usersLocation = psUsersLocation.executeQuery();
// Do whatever with the locations
```

Keep in mind this can fail/work wrong because most DB have a limit for how many items an SQL `IN` clause can include. Also this second method might allow an SQL injection on the `%a` replacement.

Comment: so in this case, if there are 1000 user ids, then the query will execute 1000 times, is there any way to execute this query as a batch?

Comment: Edited for one query for all users.

Comment: thanks for this solution, the number of user_ids can varies,i cant limit it,do you know any other way to implement this without any limitation.

Comment: You already selected a correct answer (which btw is the same as mine but posted later and less detailed), so I understand you solved your problem. Don't count on me answering any question of yours again.

Comment: sory im a newbie to stackoverflow,i actually marked both answers are correct

Comment: Sorry, you can only mark one answer as correct. AFAIK there's no other way to do it in batch. The limit in `IN` clause is a DB server limitation. You can test how much it is in your server and perform several queries for each set of users.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [FEDERATED Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html). The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables. This may not be very efficient but it will do the work (JOINs).

Answer (score 1):

If you can do away with join, one possible way is to get all the user_id's from tableA in one go, and then pass the user_id's to tableB at once. Of course, this approach will require you to change code as well.

Something like:

```
select user_id from tableA (of databaseA);
```

and

```
select user_id, location from tableB (of database B) where user_id in (<result_from_above_query)
```

The above process will require two queries.